# RegisterStartupScript only runs the first time. ASP.NET C# JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an .aspx page with the following code

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="ImagePanel">
   <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="ImageUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional"><ContentTemplate>      
      <img id="photo" src="/Icons/Factory Layout.png" style="display: none;"/>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          function ResetImage(typeOfImage) {
              var factoryImage = $("#photo");  
                if (typeOfImage === 1) {
                    factoryImage.attr("src",document.getElementById('<%= FactoryImageFileNameHF.ClientID %>').value);
                }
                else if (typeOfImage === 2) {
                    factoryImage.attr("src",document.getElementById('<%= IncidentFactoryImageFileNameHF.ClientID %>').value);
                }
```

It is the ResetImage `javascript` function that I am trying to run with the following code in the code behind.

```
if (typeOfMap == 1)
{
     FactoryImageFileNameHF.Value = fileNameOfFactoryImage.FileFullPath();
     ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "test" + ScriptKeyHF.Value, "ResetImage(1);", true);
     ScriptKeyHF.Value = (ScriptKeyHF.Value.ToInt() + 1).ToString();
 }
 else if (typeOfMap == 2)
 {
      IncidentFactoryImageFileNameHF.Value = fileNameOfFactoryImage.FileFullPath();
      ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "test" + ScriptKeyHF.Value, "ResetImage(2);", true);
      ScriptKeyHF.Value = (ScriptKeyHF.Value.ToInt() + 1).ToString();
  }
```

The problem is that the ResetImage() method that I am calling in the `RegisterStartUpScript` only runs the first time on the browser. It doesn't run the second and third time of postbacks, etc. 
I have tried the `RegisterClientScriptBlock` but it runs before the `javascript` code is there. Does anyone have any idea why the code only runs the first time.

Comment: There are details missing from the question. When is the code that registers the startup script called? Is it getting called on each postback? Is the required condition (`typeOfMap` equals 1 or 2) true?

Comment: @Scott Hannen The code that registers the start up script is a button click and typeOfMap we can assume is 1. I can confirm that with a breakpoint it gets hit(that is the RegisterStartupScript get hit). Also the first time the button gets clicked it gets hit (that is the RegisterStartupScript get hit) and so does the method in javascript but the next time the button is clicked the javascript method does not get hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that I was using a ClientScriptManager (ClientScript) instead of the a ScriptManager so I changed the line of code to

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page,Page.GetType(), "test" + ScriptKeyHF.Value, "ResetImage(1);", true);
```

and it works.

I have the ScriptManager on a Master page and my code was on a child page